# MySQL REGEXP not ignoring hyphens

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to return customers in our database that have special characters in their email address (other than `+ . - @ _`). Here is my current query:

```
SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName, Email 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Email REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9\\@\\.\\-\\+\\_]' and Active = 1 and Enabled = 1;
```

But the data set returned still contains emails like `john-smith@something.com`. Shouldn't this REGEXP be ignoring email addresses like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from the hyphen that is used in a character class to define a range, so it isn't seen as a literal character. Try to write this:

```
Email REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9@.+_-]'
```

If you put it at the end (or at the start) it is no more ambigous.

Comment: Yes you were right, moving the hyphen to the end of the expression worked. I ended up with `[^A-Za-z0-9\\@\\.\\+\\_\\-]`

Comment: @Houdini: You don't need to escape the characters inside a character class. `@` and `_` are not  special in a regex pattern, and `.` and `+` loose their special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: Thank you! I did that to be safe but I was wondering about that.